# Remove rows of dataframe of values in a list present in another list

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm attempting to remove the rows of values in a list within `df` which are present in `lst`.

I'm aware of using `df[df[x].isin(y)]` for singular strings but am not sure as to how to adjust the same method to work with lists within a `dataframe`.

```
lst = ['f','a']
```

`df`:

```
           Column1            Out1
0          ['x', 'y']         a
1          ['a', 'b']         i
2          ['c', 'd']         o
3          ['e', 'f']         u
etc.
```

I've attempted to use list comprehension but it doesn't seem to work the same with `Pandas`

```
df = df[[i for x in list for i in df['Column1']]]
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

My ***expected output*** would be as followed; removing the rows that contain the lists of which have the values in `lst`:

```
           Column1            Out1
0          ['x', 'y']         a
1          ['c', 'd']         o
etc.
```

Comment: You might as well just loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use convert values to `set`s and then use `&`, for inverting mask use `~`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':[['x','y'], ['a','b'], ['c','d'],['e','f']],
                   'Out1':list('aiou')})

lst = ['f','a']
df1 = df[~(df['Column1'].apply(set) & set(lst))]
print (df1)
  Column1 Out1
0  [x, y]    a
2  [c, d]    o
```

Solution with `nested list comprehension` - get list of `boolean`s, so need `all` for check if all values are `True`:

```
df1 =df[[all([x not in lst for x in i]) for i in df['Column1']]]
print (df1)
  Column1 Out1
0  [x, y]    a
2  [c, d]    o
```

---

```
print ([[x not in lst for x in i] for i in df['Column1']])
[[True, True], [False, True], [True, True], [True, False]]
```

Comment: My saviour! Thank again :-)

Comment: I'm encountering a slight problem. The code you suggested seems to work fine  when `lst` already contains something e.g. `'f'` and `'a'`. However, if I append something to `lst`, and then run the code, it doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, it should works. Unfortunately now I am going to bed, but tomorrow I can check. Is possible change question with your problem? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, Don't worry. I adjusted it slightly and it seems to work! Thank You =)